# operator new doesn't return 0 when running out of memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, out-of-memory, new-operator, bad-alloc

I found this interesting exercise in Bruce Eckel's *Thinking in C++, 2nd ed., Vol.1* in Chapter 13:

```
/*13. Modify NoMemory.cpp so that it contains an array of int
and so that it actually allocates memory instead of
throwing bad_alloc. In main( ), set up a while loop like
the one in NewHandler.cpp to run out of memory and
see what happens if your operator new does not test to
see if the memory is successfully allocated. Then add the
check to your operator new and throw bad_alloc*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new> // bad_alloc definition
using namespace std;

int count = 0;


class NoMemory {
  int array[100000];
public:
  void* operator new(size_t sz) throw(bad_alloc)
  {
    void* p = ::new char[sz];
    if(!p)
    {
      throw bad_alloc(); // "Out of memory"
    }
    return p;
  }
};


int main() {

  try {
    while(1) {
      count++;
      new NoMemory();
    }
  }
  catch(bad_alloc)
  {
    cout << "memory exhausted after " << count << " allocations!" << endl;
    cout << "Out of memory exception" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

My question is: why does this code does not throw the `bad_alloc`, when ran completely out of memory (as per the Task Manager's resource monitor on Win7)?
I assume the global `::new char[sz]` never returns with 0, even if the memory is full. But why? It even turns the Win7 OS into a numb, non-responding state once ran out of memory, still is does keep on trying to allocate new space.

(One interesting addition: I tryed it on Ubuntu too: the `bad_alloc` is not thrown either, still this OS does not goes frozen but this dangerous  process gets killed before by the OS - smart isn't it?)

Comment: [OT] It was already explained here that windows's task manager does not show **real** resource usage.

Comment: Run out of memory means that you've allocated all RAM **and** there's no space left to grow the swap file. This isn't specific to Windows, it applies to all operating systems.

Comment: Don't know how you do this in Windows, but in linux you can use `ulimit` to reduce the amount of available memory to a particular process, and then you'd get out of memory before the process gets killed.

Comment: If you have 64-bit windows, and more than 4GB of RAM, you could also try to build a 32-bit application.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow

Comment: @Victor Polevoy: So if I understand right, I should call like this `void* p = ::new(std::nothrow) char[sz];` to make this `new` statement return 0, if allocation fails. I tried this way, but the result is the same: the app keeps on trying allocating after memory is filled up, and freezes Windows. What do I still do wrong?

Comment: @Janos no, this will lead to kill by OOM Killer, so it will be the same. The same behaviour you will achieve by `new (noexcept version)` and `malloc` because the OS always handle this. You may try to limit your app memory access by `ulimit` and I believe this will allow your application to do what you expect. Otherwise, read the `OOM Killer` policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my error: I called `new` wrong: `new NoMemory();`
The correct way to do is `new NoMemory;` (without the parentheses)

Now it works like a charm, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new> // bad_alloc definition
using namespace std;

int count = 0;

class NoMemory {
  int array[100000];
public:

  void* operator new(size_t sz) throw(bad_alloc)
  { 
    void* p = ::new(std::nothrow) char[sz];
    if(0 != p)
      return p;
    throw bad_alloc();
  }
};


int main() {
  try {
    while(1) {
      count++;
      new NoMemory;
    }
  }
  catch(bad_alloc)
  {
    cout << "memory exhausted after " << count << " allocations!" << endl;
    cout << "Out of memory exception" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of operator new is incorrect.

```
void* operator new(size_t sz) throw(bad_alloc)
{
  void* p = ::new char[sz];
  if(!p)
  {
    throw bad_alloc(); // "Out of memory"
  }
  return p;
}
```

`::new` already throws `std::bad_alloc` and you don't need to check return value of `p` pointer.

If you look `g++`'s [libstdc++ source](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc?view=markup), they compare pointer to null after `malloc`, so you should do that too in order to simulate this:

```
_GLIBCXX_WEAK_DEFINITION void *
operator new (std::size_t sz) _GLIBCXX_THROW (std::bad_alloc)
{
  void *p;

  /* malloc (0) is unpredictable; avoid it.  */
  if (sz == 0)
    sz = 1;

  while (__builtin_expect ((p = malloc (sz)) == 0, false))
    {
      new_handler handler = std::get_new_handler ();
      if (! handler)
        _GLIBCXX_THROW_OR_ABORT(bad_alloc());
      handler ();
    }

  return p;
}
```

So it does not return `0` but throws an `exception`. The reason why don't you get it on linux I believe is that the process is always killed by the kernel ([OOM-Killer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-oom-killer-decides-which-process-to-kill-first)) in such cases.

As @MarcGlisse pointed you may want to use `nothrow` (noexcept) version of `new`:

```
_GLIBCXX_WEAK_DEFINITION void *
operator new (std::size_t sz, const std::nothrow_t&) GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
{
  void *p;

  /* malloc (0) is unpredictable; avoid it.  */
  if (sz == 0)
    sz = 1;

  while (__builtin_expect ((p = malloc (sz)) == 0, false))
    {
      new_handler handler = std::get_new_handler ();
      if (! handler)
        return 0;
      __try
        {
          handler ();
        }
      __catch(const bad_alloc&)
        {
          return 0;
        }
    }

  return p;
}
```

As you see it will return 0 if allocation fails and it will catch all exceptions that can be raised by `new_handler`. Default `new_handler` throws `std::bad_alloc`.
But even in this case I think `OOM-Killer` will kill your application before you get something. If your question is more about `why is it killed?` then I recommend you to read about `OOM killer` policy.